# Unable to push to SSH Git remote: remote unpack failed

Tags: ssh, freebsd, git

I'm working on setting up a Git repo on my homelab network. I have ssh: working for `clone`, but I can't `push` - when I `git push --set-upstream origin master` I get the message

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 524 bytes | 524.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory
To anubis.local:/var/www/apache24/git/TDD2.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dave@anubis.local:/var/www/apache24/git/TDD2.git'
```

I've been following the instructions at [Git Book: Git on the Server - Setting Up the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) but obviously I've missed something. Can anyone point out to me what it is? I'm using git 2.38.0 on FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE for the server.

Comment: That looks like a user filesystem permission issue. Ensure the dave user can write to that directory.

Comment: @jordanm I knew it was going to be something simple like that.